# How to Paste a Border Image (Constant) over Multiple Thumbnail Images?

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library

Here is what i'm trying to achieve:

1. Resize Multiple Product images into 500 x 500 pixels
2. Paste all of these resized images individually onto a 800 x 800 image and output as individual images

For now, I have managed to complete Step 1, but have no idea how to proceed to step 2. Here is my code for Step 1:

```
from PIL import Image
import os, sys

path = "C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\Test\\"
dirs = os.listdir( path )
final_size = 500;

def resize_aspect_fit():
    for item in dirs:
         if item == '.png':
             continue
         if os.path.isfile(path+item):
             im = Image.open(path+item)
             f, e = os.path.splitext(path+item)
             size = im.size
             ratio = float(final_size) / max(size)
             new_image_size = tuple([int(x*ratio) for x in size])
             im = im.resize(new_image_size, Image.ANTIALIAS)
             new_im = Image.new("RGBA", (final_size, final_size), (255,255,255,000))

             new_im.paste(im, ((final_size-new_image_size[0])//2, (final_size-new_image_size[1])//2))
             new_im.save(f + 'resized.png', 'PNG', quality=100)
resize_aspect_fit()
```

Thanks!

Edit:

Here's an image illustration for better explanation of what i am trying to achieve. I have 2 smiley faces (500 x 500) which i need to paste over the default 800 x 800 image multiple times (centered) to produce 2 separate images of 800 x 800.

Example

[image]

Comment: What exactly you want to achieve, an image grid on 800x800 image?

Comment: Please refer to this link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/69CfF.png 

Essentially, I want to achieve a final image of 800 x 800 (which is the larger of the two images).

I have multiple 500 x 500 images that i want to paste over the 800 x 800 image (all of which would be needed as individual images on their own, not an image grid). - sorry if i wasn't too clear on that!

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're nearly there, you can use .paste() with an offset to paste into the middle over your image. a little bit like:

```
Border_im = Image.open(pathToBorder)
product_im = Image.open(pathToProduct)
x_offset=150;
y_offset=150;
Border_im.paste(product_im, (x_offset,y_offset))
```

Then save out border_im to a new file

Comment: Thanks Jeff! That worked. However, I’m not really sure how to loop this throughout my multiple 500 x 500 images while ensuring the 800 x 800 remains constant. Could you advice once more?

Comment: Basically, you need to put a loop around the code that loads the product image, pastes its, and saves it.  Give it a go and if you find a specific problem that you can't solve with your own research online, feel free to pose another questions.